# Sierra Wireless EM7455 No Signal

Tags: wireless-networking, wan, aircard

I bought a Sierra wireless EM7455 for my new Thinkpad P40 laptop. I was able to get the driver installed and windows recognizes the modem, SIM and GPS however it will not connect to the cellular network. I added it to my plan with Verizon and they confirmed the IMEI and SIM are activated. Windows says "No Service" and running a command shows 0% Signal and roaming appears to be off. I'm thinking all I need to do is enable roaming or possible the radio but I can't seem to figure out what needs to be done. The best suggestion I have seen so far is to load Linux on a flashdrive and booting and run a config utility but I would like to think there is a simple solution I am overlooking.

```
C:\>netsh mbn sh int

There is 1 interface on the system:

Name : Cellular
Description : Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
GUID : {---E-44-F-45-------}
Physical Address : b4:--:--:--:--:--
State : Not connected
Device type : This is a remote device
Cellular class : GSM
Device Id : 0145....
Manufacturer : Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
Model : Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm
Firmware Version : SWI9X30C_02.20.03.22
Provider Name :
Roaming : Not roaming
Signal : 0%
RSSI / RSCP : 0 (-113 dBm)
```

Comment: do you have appropriate antennas? Thinkpads have been known to have blacklists for devices but this feels like its not the case here, so I'm leaning towards the antenna. What interface does this use?

Comment: There are 3 antennas with IPEX MHF4 connectors ( LTE MIMO ANT 1, ANT 2 and GPS). I could not find an official EM7455 antenna set so I ended up buying something that looked right off ebay. With this I was able to get it to connect to Verizon however the signal is very low and it only works in certain areas. In general it's quite useless. I also found a new issue where my screen will "blink" as if you are rapidly connecting and disconnecting an external monitor while the EM7455 is operating.

Comment: Can you add a link to the antennas you bought. If they aren't tuned to the LTE frequencies they will be anntenuating the signal rather then boosting it. If the wavelength doesn't match, essentially those antennas will be black holes to the receiver.